# group by date of timestamp

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

How can you group by a the date portion of a timestamp column in mysql and still take advantage of an index on that ?

Of course you can use solutions like

```
select date(thetime) from mytable group by date(thetime)
```

however this query will not be able to use an index on thetime but will instead require a temporary table as you are transforming the column using a function before grouping by it.

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable     | index | NULL          | thetime     | 4       | NULL | 48183 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Theoretically there's no reason why it shouldn't be able to use a range scan on an index on that column and not need a temporary table. Is there any syntax that can persuade the query optimizer to execute the query to do that?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand the database already does what you want? The index is being scanned (rather than the table itself) as evident in xplan.

But you cannot get around the fact that an intermediate table is needed to hold the dates during the grouping (distinct) operation.

Comment: You don't always need a temporary table to perform group by on an indexed column if you don't mutate it using a function. If there were an operator rather than a function to truncate the time portion it might work

Comment: @x: Hmm, I think we are both right. As long there are no aggregate functions applied, a list of distinct values can (theoretically) be obtained by walking the index, keeping only the previously output value for comparison. When performing a count/sum etc all values needs to be maintained until the end of the grouping operation. The question is: is this implemented in the database? :)